# Install multiple vs code extensions in CICD

Tags: github-actions, vscode-extensions, cicd

My unit test launch looks like this. As you can see I have exploited CLI options to install a VSIX my CICD has already produced, and then also tried to install `ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh` because I want to re-run the tests on a remote workspace.

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';

import { runTests } from '@vscode/test-electron';

async function main() {
    try {
        // The folder containing the Extension Manifest package.json
        // Passed to `--extensionDevelopmentPath`
        const extensionDevelopmentPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../');

        // The path to the extension test runner script
        // Passed to --extensionTestsPath
        const extensionTestsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './suite/index');

        const vsixName = fs.readdirSync(extensionDevelopmentPath)
            .filter(p => path.extname(p) === ".vsix")
            .sort((a, b) => a < b ? 1 : a > b ? -1 : 0)[0];

        const launchArgsLocal = [
            path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src/test/test-docs'),
            "--install-extension",
            vsixName,
            "--install-extension",
            "ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh"
        ];
        const SSH_HOST = process.argv[2];
        const SSH_WORKSPACE = process.argv[3];
        const launchArgsRemote = [
            "--folder-uri",
            `vscode-remote://ssh-remote+testuser@${SSH_HOST}${SSH_WORKSPACE}`
        ];

        // Download VS Code, unzip it and run the integration test
        await runTests({ extensionDevelopmentPath, extensionTestsPath, launchArgs: launchArgsLocal });
        await runTests({ extensionDevelopmentPath, extensionTestsPath, launchArgs: launchArgsRemote });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        console.error('Failed to run tests');
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

runTests downloads and installs VS Code, and passes through the parameters I supply. For the local file system all the tests pass, so the extension from the VSIX is definitely installed.

But `ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh` doesn't seem to be installed - I get this error:

```
Cannot get canonical URI because no extension is installed to resolve ssh-remote
```

and then the tests fail because there's no open workspace.

This may be related to the fact that CLI installation of multiple extensions repeats the `--install-extension` switch. I suspect the switch name is used as a hash key.

What to do? Well, I'm not committed to any particular course of action, just platform independence. If I knew how to do a platform independent headless CLI installation of VS Code:latest in a GitHub Action, that would certainly do the trick. I could then directly use the CLI to install the extensions *before* the tests, and pass the installation path. Which would also require a unified way to get the path for vs code.

## Update 2022-07-20

Having figured out how to do a platform independent headless CLI installation of VS Code:latest in a GitHub Action followed by installation of the required extensions I face new problems.

The test framework options include a path to an existing installation of VS Code. According to the interface documentation, supplying this should cause the test to use the existing installation instead of installing VS Code; this is why I thought the above installation would solve my problems.

However, the option seems to be ignored.

My latest iteration uses an extension dependency on remote-ssh to install it. There's a new problem: how to get the correct version of my extension onto the *remote* host. By default the remote host uses the marketplace version, which obviously won't be the version we're trying to test.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Yes and no. I managed to set up all the YAML to prep VS Code and the extensions, and now I'm having trouble getting the test framework to use the existing installation despite the fact that there is a documented option for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try with only one `--install-extension` option, just to check if any extension is installed.

I would also check if the same set of commands works locally (install VSCode and its [remote SSH extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh))
Testing it locally (with only one extension) also allows to check if that extension has any dependencies (like [Remote SSH - Editing](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit))